# VMWare Fusion annoyance - fullscreen hiding dock and menu bar

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I'm running a multi-monitor setup with one fusion running fullscreen to one of them and my OSX doc on another. When focused on fusion, the mac menu bar and dock disappear. This is annoying since then I need to constantly switch to another app just to get back to the dock or see the menu bar.

The fusion "Hide Menu Bar in Fullscreen option" doesn't seem to work at un-hiding the dock or menu bar.

Running OSX 10.8.4, VMWare Fusion 5.0.3, with a Win7 vm (all updated to current versions as of this post).

Thanks in advance for anyone with constructive ideas to help solve this!

Comment: I don't know about Win7, but I know with my Linux VM I can just move the mouse to the very top of the screen and the menu bar and dock will appear after a second or so.